Is building a retainer wall my only option?
Our house foundation in construction now is  2ft away from the road as well as 2ft below the road level.  Do I have any other option besides building a retaining  wall to avoid rain from flowing  in the house direction?

2ft away and 2ft below, I would build up/raise the land, unless you want a moat.

And you're just dealing with this now?

@crip659   and a draw bridge.

The distances sound ridiculous. Is 2 feet and 2 feet correct ?  There isn't any reasonable set back.  As Jack suggested this should have been addressed at the planning stage.

Nothing stops water from flowing downhill. The best you can do is redirect it. I agree with the others that drainage should have been addressed in the plans for the foundation. If you haven’t paid the foundation contractor yet then you might renegotiate something.

@RMDman   ~2ft from the road might be.  The closest town/village to me has the power poles in the road beside the sidewalk.  Front doors on the other side of the small sidewalk.  I get to walk over 100ft to the mailbox.  Up hill both ways though three feet of snow.

@crip,  I understand old towns. There is some areas like that around me too. However nothing can be constructed new, even remotely close to the road.

I'm surprised no one has asked for pics yet...

what does the architect or engineer say who designed the foundation?

She said they will put some 3x12 and lay them horizontal to press against the vertical area where the walkway drop off to our yard ground level.  Seems to be more concern about soil erosion being an issue with the city inspection more so than the water runoff
